# data role not apply to the items appended by javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, webview

I am working on android webview program and tried to append list item dynamically to the page. However, the data-role = "listview" does not apply to this new ul list. Please help. Following is the javascript code.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {

            var listposts = window.jsinterface.getPostValue();
            $('#postlist').append(listposts);

        });
```

Following is the corresponding html code.

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content" id ="clientsdiv" style= "overflow: auto">

        <ul data-role="listview" id="postlist">

        </ul>

    </div><!-- /content -->
```

Comment: refresh the listview after appending.

Comment: Thanks, beginner. I am toally a beginner!!!

Comment: $('#postlist').append(listposts).listview("refresh");

Comment: Did it work for you??

Comment: Yes, Beginner. It works!!!! Thank you so much. anyway I can give you credits?